# Equivalents of Oxalic acid

Tags: stoichiometry

[image]

In this question the answer key given is A and C. But i think that D should also be wrong because equivalents = molecular mass / n factor = $\frac{90}{2} = 45 \neq 40 $

I believe I am correct but I may be wrong so can someone please help me clarify my question.

Comment: The reaction (ii) is incorrectly enumerated in the first place. The wording of (D) does not make sense and the whole question has inferior quality.

Comment: `+1` for the OP bringing a problematic question here and asking for guidance. I can't understand the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Poutnik's point that this is a poor question.

Oxalic acid has two acidic protons so its equivalent weight is $\frac{1}{2}$ its molecular weight. Thus:

- Answer **A** is false.
- Answer **B** is true.
- Answer **C** is false since there are 2*100*0.2 = 40 milliequivalents of acid, but only 100*0.2 = 20 milliequivalents of base.

Answer **D** requires some extra work. First it is not clear if Answer **D** applies to both *reaction (i)* and *reaction (ii)*

- For *reaction (i)*, in 100 ml of 0.2 M oxalic acid there are 40 milliequivalents of acid
- For *reaction (ii)*, the reaction is a redox reaction, so the number of electrons exchanged by oxalic acid needs to be determined.

  Here is another sloppy point about the question. *Reaction (ii)* is not balanced.

  However to figure out the number of electrons exchanged by oxalic acid, we only need the half cell reaction which is:

$\quad\quad\ce{2CO2(g) + 2 H+ + 2e− <=> HOOCCOOH(aq)}$

$\quad\quad$ Since oxalic acid exchanges two electrons in the redox reaction,
its "redox" equivalent
$\quad\quad$ weight is $\frac{1}{2}$ its molecular weight.Thus there are also there are 40 milliequivalents of
$\quad\quad$ oxalic acid redox wise too.

- Answer **D** is false, because there are 40 *milliequivalents* of oxalic acid, not 40 *equivalents*

Comment: Answer **D** is true only if it states that "milliequivalents of oxalic acid in..."

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne - Thank you for the correction. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Okay but isn't oxalic acid's meq = 45 because 90/2 @MaxW.

Comment: @user198885 - No, 100 ml of 0.2 molar solution is 20 **milli**moles of oxalic acid. In a redox reaction because there are 2 electrons per molecule of oxalic acid that is 40 **milli**equivalents of oxalic acid. Answer D refers to 40 *equivalents* not 40 *milliequivalents*.